# Get Windows login name for web application is using Tomcat to host the application

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

I have an application in JSF 2.2 that is using localHost and Apache tomcat as a server to deploy the application .
I wanted to extract the client who accesses  the local Host URL as the systems are connected via Lan and sharing ip and the path makes the application work in a small unit.

I have tried using `String username = System.getProperty("user.name");`
But its is giving the username of the local system where the server is hosted.
where as i want the username of the client who is accesing the local url .

I even tried using `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();`

But it is returing NULL.

I am not using a dedicated server instead using local system as one and just want the windows login name of the person accessing the local URL.

Comment: I donot want a username password auth , i only want to pick up the username to be displayed to the user when he visits my local page.

Comment: Balus I am not getting it actually , sorry for sounding so silly but can you please explain it in detail